# Integrating(Using) iCloud in iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, import, upload, icloud

I have simple text file generated in my application. The thing is I want to upload this text file on iCloud so that if the user installs app and inputs data he desires and then agin uninstalls this app. Then the next time he installs that app again I want to fetch the text file uploaded the first time he had used the same app.

I am facing a huge problem in integrating iCloud to my app.
I have done much research but didn't got any specific answers. 
P.S. = I am not using Core data.

All i want is to upload the text file generated by the app into the iCloud Drive.

Please guide me step by step how can I achieve this. I have my developer account and I have a bit knowledge about the certificates and all. But still if anyone can please guide me how to achieve it.

I JUST WANT TO UPLOAD THE TEXT FILE TO ICLOUD AND RETRIEVE IT AGAIN WHEN THE SAME APP IS INSTALLED AGAIN (EVEN IF THE APP IS GETTING INSTALLED ON OTHER DEVICES).

ViewController.m

```
  #pragma mark - Image Pick
- (IBAction)pickImage:(id)sender {

    //select an image

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageView.image = image;


    //SAVE IMAGE IN iCloud

    AppDelegate* myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSURL* cloudeImage = [myAppDelegate applicationCloudFolder:@"thePicture"];
    NSData* imageDate = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    [imageDate writeToURL:cloudeImage atomically:YES];

}


-(void)populateUI
{
    AppDelegate* myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSURL* cloudeImageURL = [myAppDelegate applicationCloudFolder:@"thePicture"];
    NSData* imageDate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:cloudeImageURL];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDate];
    if (image) {
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }
    else
    {
        //download image from iCloud
        NSLog(@"Downloading Image...");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:cloudeImageURL error:nil];


    }

}


- (NSMetadataQuery *)query {
    if (!_query) {
        _query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc]init];

        NSArray *scopes = @[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope];
        _query.searchScopes = scopes;

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"*"];
        _query.predicate = predicate;

        if (![_query startQuery]) {
            NSLog(@"Query didn't start... for whatever reason");
        }
    }
    return _query;
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    -(NSURL*)applicationCloudFolder:(NSString*)fileName
{

    //TEAM ID AND CONTAINER ID

    NSString* teamID = @"V58ESG9PLE";
    NSString* bundelID =[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier;
    NSString* containerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",teamID,bundelID];

    // URL to Cloud Folder
    NSURL* cloudeRootURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:containerID];
    NSLog(@"cloudeRootURL %@",cloudeRootURL);

    NSURL* cloudDocuments = [cloudeRootURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Document"];

    //Apend our file name

    cloudDocuments = [cloudDocuments URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



    return cloudDocuments;
}
```

Now I am not getting is my data being saved? ,Where is it getting saved? how can I retrieve it?

P.S. I am saving a picture

Comment: i have facing same issue

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried? https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/icloud-drive-documents-1a46b5706fe1#.wtp5niyya

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I can.. Can u just tell me the least things that are expected for mr to do. I have too much things in the code. Can u also guide me what actual screenshots do u need.